# Emoji to UIImage for use on slider.setThumbImage

Tags: swift, uiimage, slider, emoji

Does anyone know if it is possible to set an emoji from unicode on the setThumbImage property of a slider in Swift?

I have tried converting string to NSData and then using it in UIImage however this failed.

/noob learning by coding.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Emoji in UILabel then UILabel to image.

Comment: Got it working. Thanks for the directional push!